# "Floating" sidebar dentro de um elemento ao fazer scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho um *layout* Bootstrap com uma barra lateral à direita e preciso que esta "rode" (para cima/baixo) quando se faz *scroll*, mas que não fique em cima do cabeçalho e do rodapé. que apenas "flutue" dentro do `div[role=main]`

**Minha layout:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu código:**

```
<header class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Header</div>
    </div>
</header>

<div role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
            Main Content
        </div>

        <aside class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
            <section class="budget-summary">
                <h2 class="text-center">Resumo</h2>                
            </section>
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Footer</div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

EDIT:

Consegui por a barra a rodar com o plugin affix do bootstrap:

```
$('.budget-summary').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = $('footer#page-footer').outerHeight(true));
        }
    }
});
```

no entanto agora surgiu um problema.
O conteúdo da barra lateral é dinâmico (cresce e diminui). o que faz com que às vezes o conteúdo da barra lateral não seja mostrado na totalidade, como exemplifica a seguinte figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

há forma de contornar isto?

Comment: Miguel: conseguiste resolver o problema?

Comment: parcialmente...

Comment: O que está a faltar?

Comment: está na pergunta. quando o conteudo é aumentado, fica cortado

Comment: Miguel, olhando o seu edit, parece o caso de uma pergunta nova, separada, em vez de uma edição nesta. Porque o problema agora mudou, certo? A nova pergunta não invalida as respostas que você já recebeu?

Comment: tens razao. abri um nova http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44972/affix-numa-barra-lateral-dinamica

Comment: Miguel vi agora a tua pergunta nova. Testaste a resposta que dei? nessa resposta o código adapta-se à altura da barra lateral.

Comment: sim, tentei, mas tinha mts bugs, e como o bootstrap ja traz um plugin para o k keria, é mais facil de o usar. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das funcionalidades do Bootstrap faz justamente o que você quer, o [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix). o único requisito é adicionar um estilo `position: absolute` ao elemento que você deseja fixar e rodar um código JS para inicializar o comportamento.

http://jsfiddle.net/mryvo4tL/1/embedded/result/

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. tentei desse jeito mas nao funcionou correctamente. adicionei o ```affix-top``` à sidebar e a barra começou a rodar, mas quando se faz scroll ela encolhe, quando chega ao fundo da página fica com a largura normal, e deixa de funcionar (fica outra vez no inicio da página). quando adiciono o ```position:absolute``` deixa de funcionar de todo.

http://prntscr.com/5hx3md
http://prntscr.com/5hx3ul
http://prntscr.com/5hx44o

Comment: @MiguelBorges eu atualizei a resposta pois eu me enganei quanto ao `affix-top`, ele não é um requisito para o funcionamento. Apenas com as imagens que você colocou não é possível descobrir qual o problema. Você poderia colocar um link para o site ou criar um JSFiddle? Tente também utilizar o console do browser para ver o que muda do css no elemento em cada estado, talvez o que você precise seja apenas acrescentar a propriedade `width` com um valor fixo ou `100%`.

Comment: obrigado. o problema era que tinha que indicar uma width e colocar o seguinte estilo para ele nao saltar quando chega-se ao fundo (```.affix-bottom { position: absolute; }```). no entanto agora surgiu um outro problema. actualizei a pergunta

Comment: @MiguelBorges o problema quanto a altura acontece pelo fato desse `position: absolute` no `.affix-bottom` visto que o plugin seta o atributo `top` do elemento. Tente procurar soluções para o seu problema anterior que acredito ser mais fácil de resolver. Utilize o console do navegador e faça tentativas com os seus conhecimentos. Dá até para aprender coisas novas sobre o CSS quando se tenta resolver estes problemas. =)

Answer (score 6):

Vai ter de usar JavaScript para ler o scroll e mudar a posição dessa barra lateral.

Uma sugestão (usando jQuery pois presumo que usando o Bootstrap tenha jQuery) é:

```
var main = $('div[role=main]').outerHeight();
var posicaoFooter = $('footer').offset().top;
var sidebarDiv = $('aside');

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll + sidebarDiv.outerHeight() < main) sidebarDiv.css('margin-top', scroll);
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/s8h9eeL0/

Neste código quando o scroll acontece ele vai comparar o valor do scroll + a altura da barra lateral e vai mudando a posição enquanto esse valor junto fôr menor que a altura total do `main`. Talvez precise de ajustes de CSS mas acho que é esta ideia que precisa e pode ver no exemplo como funciona.