# Affix numa barra lateral dinamica

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho um layout Bootstrap com uma barra lateral à direita que acompanha o scroll, dentro do `div[role=main]`.

**Minha layout:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu código:**

```
<header class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Header</div>
    </div>
</header>

<div role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
            Main Content
        </div>

        <aside class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
            <section class="budget-summary">
                <h2 class="text-center">Resumo</h2>                
            </section>
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Footer</div>
    </div>
</footer>


$('.budget-summary').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = $('footer#page-footer').outerHeight(true));
        }
    }
});
```

no entanto o conteúdo da barra lateral é dinâmico (cresce e diminui). o que faz com que às vezes o conteúdo da barra lateral não seja mostrado na totalidade, como exemplifica a seguinte figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

há forma de contornar isto?

Comment: Essa questão foi solucionada? Ou ainda precisa de ajuda com isso?

Comment: nao foi. se poderes ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

No seu código você está falando que quando ele rolar (`top: 0`) 0 pixels ele vai aplicar a posição fixa. Então no seu CSS você tem que definir a posição dele no caso:

```
.budget-summary {
    top: 0;
}
```

*o Off-set top que você define no javascript é quanto deve rolar para aplicar a posição. Não a posição depois de fixo.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar a div que contém o .budget-summary com a altura total da página e botar um overflow=auto na mesma. Assim, ao preencher todo espaço disponível na "altura", será exibido uma barra de rolagem somente para aquela div.